# Implement x86 to x64 assembly code switch

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64, ntdll

I was looking how `NtDll` works for x86 processes, and i debugged the function `NtCreateFile` using IDA PRO. The code for it is following:

```
mov     eax, 55h        ; NtCreateFile
mov     edx, offset _Wow64SystemServiceCall@0 ; 
call    edx ; Wow64SystemServiceCall() ; 
retn    2Ch
```

And the `Wow64SystemServiceCall()`:

```
mov     edx, large fs:30h
mov     edx, [edx+464h]
test    edx, 2
jz      short loc_7738B5C8
int     2Eh             ; DOS 2+ internal - EXECUTE COMMAND
                        ; DS:SI -> counted CR-terminated command string
retn
loc_7738B5C8:                           ; CODE XREF: 
jmp     far ptr byte_7738B8FF
```

I looked up the command code for `jmp     far ptr byte_7738B8FF` 
and it was `EA CF B5 38 77 33 00` which is a jump to another segment, 0x33 `jmp 0x33:0x7738b5cf` . So from what i read in internet, this is the x64 segment base for processes on 64-bit systems, right? Unfortunately i cannot debug further, because, ida doesnt follow the jump. But i made another simple C application compiled for x64, and called `CreateFile`, attached x64 IDA PRO Remote debugger, and looked up disassembly, and `NtCreateFile` was looking like so:

```
x64_NtCreateFile proc near  
mov     r10, rcx
mov     eax, 55h
test    byte ptr ds:7FFE0308h, 1
jnz     short loc_7FFED6695B85
syscall
retn
loc_7FFED6695B85:                     
int     2Eh             ; DOS 2+ internal - EXECUTE COMMAND
                        ; DS:SI -> counted CR-terminated command string
retn
```

So i have a few question, how does the jump from x86 process attached ntdll far jump `jmp 0x33:0x7738b5cf` just lands into `x64_NtCreateFile` first instruction? How does the switching from x86 to x64 happens in this case exactly? Basically i can just make x86 application, and switch segment with jump, and just execute the x64 code in there, which i can create by just doing something like `db (0x00) ; x64 machine code commands`, is this right?

Comment: Reading-up about the way that an OS is bootstrapped may be beneficial to you here. First the 16bit -> 32bit transition and then later, the 32 --> 64 bit switch.

Comment: `Unfortunately i cannot debug further, because, ida doesnt follow the jump` because ida is bad debugger. use windbg - it allow you enter into jump

Comment: @RbMm thanks for Advice. I tried it and it was less comfortable, but better in terms of disassembly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the bytes at address `0x7738b5cf`, you would see something like

`41 FF A7 F8 00 00 00` (at least if you're on Windows 8.1 or newer)

which corresponds to a single x86_64 instruction `jmp QWORD PTR [r15+0xf8]`.

Right after switching from 32-bit to 64-bit code execution via the far jump, the `R15` register will always point to a special jump table within `wow64cpu.dll` (the `R15` register is setup to point to this table from 64-bit code that executes before the 32-bit entry point of your application).

`[r15+0xf8]` just happens to point to the `CpupReturnFromSimulatedCode` method within `wow64cpu.dll`, which will setup the right context and perform the actual system call (in your case for `NtCreateFile`) using the `syscall` instruction.

For some information that elaborates upon this, see:

- https://duo.com/assets/pdf/wow-64-and-so-can-you.pdf
- https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/07/windows-10-system-call-stub-changes.html
- http://rce.co/knockin-on-heavens-gate-dynamic-processor-mode-switching/

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i was trying to figure out. Now i can try and direct call Nt functions with sysenter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can confirm that one can execute 64-bit code in a 32-bit Windows app running on 64-bit windows.

[Mixing x86 with x64 code](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=102) provides an explanation and an example of how to do it.

This is what I tried (adapted for and compiled with my Smaller C compiler):

```
#define EM(a) asm("db " #a);

#define X64_Start_with_CS(_cs) \
{ \
    EM(0x6A) EM(_cs)                     /*  push   _cs                   */ \
    EM(0xE8) EM(0) EM(0) EM(0) EM(0)     /*  call   $+5                   */ \
    EM(0x83) EM(4) EM(0x24) EM(5)        /*  add    dword [esp], 5        */ \
    EM(0xCB)                             /*  retf                         */ \
}

#define X64_End_with_CS(_cs) \
{ \
    EM(0xE8) EM(0) EM(0) EM(0) EM(0)     /*  call   $+5                   */ \
    EM(0xC7) EM(0x44) EM(0x24) EM(4)     /*                               */ \
    EM(_cs) EM(0) EM(0) EM(0)            /*  mov    dword [rsp + 4], _cs  */ \
    EM(0x83) EM(4) EM(0x24) EM(0xD)      /*  add    dword [rsp], 0xD      */ \
    EM(0xCB)                             /*  retf                         */ \
}

#define X64_Start() X64_Start_with_CS(0x33)
#define X64_End() X64_End_with_CS(0x23)

#define __break() asm("int3")

int main(void)
{
  __break();
  X64_Start();
  EM(0x48) EM(0x8D) EM(0x05) EM(0xF9) EM(0xFF) EM(0xFF) EM(0xFF) // lea rax, [$] ; rip-relative
  X64_End();
  __break();
}
```

I then ran it under a debugger and noticed that eax contained the address of the 64-bit instruction "lea rax, [$]" when the second break point was hit.

Comment: Thanks for answer, very helped me, i looked up the code and understood it pretty ok. Can i ask you something also, if i do for example `VirtualAlloc` with page execute/read write, and write x64 instructions there from x86 process i need to do the same segment switch trick, right?

Comment: @Vlad If you want to execute 64-bit code, CS must be loaded with a selector for 64-bit (AKA long mode) code descriptor. You change CS with far jumps, far calls, far returns.